# How to create an object for a specific user role in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Hey guys I'm trying to build a `User` `Schema` that has a `role` object like this and an `appointment` object

```
new mongoose.Schema({
role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["admin", "partner", "basic"],
    default: "basic",
  },
apponitments: {
    type: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Appointment",
      },
    ],
    required: function () {
      return this.role === "partner";
    },
  }
})
```

my problem with this code is that no matter what the `role` is the appointment object is being created anyways.

I don't want this behavior is there a way to stop it ?

Comment: not clear details, can you explain in details, what is the problem in your current schema and add use cases.

Comment: appointment object is created for all users at the moment, what I expect for example, a user with admin role should not have an appointment object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- set `default` property to `undefined` when role is `admin` otherwise return `value`,
- se `required` property to `true` when role is `admin` otherwise required `false`

```
new mongoose.Schema({
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["admin", "partner", "basic"],
        default: "basic"
    },
    apponitments: {
        type: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "Appointment"
            }
        ],
        default: function () {
            return this.role === "admin" ? undefined : this.value;
        },
        required: function () {
            return this.role === "admin" ? false : true;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: sorry for delay but this approach creates the object anyway

Comment: I have tested in mongoose v5.10.11, it is working perfectly. it is not creating field when role is admin.

Comment: oh I had an old version, just updated issue resolved!. thanks mate.